# How can I run an Erlang Service in Windows with long node names?

Tags: windows, erlang, rebar

I'm trying to get an erlang app to run as a Windows service with long node names, but the `-name` flag for `erlsrv` doesn't seem to work.  The service seems to run, but doesn't show up in `epmd` with `net_adm:names()`. However, when I use the `-sname` flag instead, it seems to work.

I'm using Rebar to generate my release scripts.  Here is the section of the script which installs the service:

```
:install
@set description=Erlang node %node_name% in %node_root%
@set start_erl=%node_root%\bin\start_erl.cmd
@set args= ++ %node_name% ++ %node_root%
@%erlsrv% add %service_name% -c "%description%" -name %node_name% -args "%args%" -w "%node_root%" -m "%start_erl%" -stopaction "init:stop()."
@goto :EOF
```

How can I get this service to work with long node names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the vm.args file specifies a name also, which can conflict with the name specified on the `erlsrv` command.  I fixed it by making a new `win_vm.args` without the `-name` parameter, and changing the `start_erl.cmd` to look for the windows version of the file.  I also changed all the `-sname` to `-name` options in the application cmd script.